# Problem when deleting account: A previous delete request is pending

Tags: support, deleted-accounts

I decided to delete my account about a month ago since I have not been using the site as much. I accessed the "Contact and Support" page and followed all the procedure to delete my user profile. I recieved an email from SE stating that I needed to login into my account and that I should've followed the link that had been posted.

However, for various reasons I postponed the deletion.

Now, when I try to access the link it states that it doesn't exist. Therefore, I tried to delete my account again, but, I get the error message:

> "Your previous delete request is pending. If you haven't heard from us in a day or two and your profile is not yet deleted, please contact us via the 'Other' topic."

Any ideas on how to solve this problem?

Comment: Have you contacted them using the "Other" topic?

Comment: The link provided to delete your account naturally expires in a short period of time. This is a security measuer taken to ensure unauthorized access to your account is not done at a later stage.

Comment: *contact us via the 'Other' topic.* does not mean posting here. Try that first, wait a day or two, and only then post here. Good luck.

Comment: It literally says what to do in the message you quoted

Comment: I was looking for a quicker way

Comment: There is no quicker way. The way to solve the problem is follow the instruction in the error you quoted.